# Sum column data while merging zip_code polygons to MultiPolygons in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I m working with python on a Jupyter notebook
I have the following dataset:

```
    +-------+------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------+
    |  zip  | population |   area#  |                     polygon                       |
    +-------+------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------+
    | 12345 | 50         | 55       | POLYGON ((-55.66788 40.04416, -55.66790 40.044... |
    | 12346 | 100        | 55       | POLYGON ((-55.54666 40.40131, -55.54678 40.400... |
    | .     | .          | .        | .                                                 |
    | .     | .          | .        | .                                                 |
    | 98765 | 236667     | 155      | POLYGON ((-155.04682 78.53585, -155.04680 78.5..  |
    +-------+--------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Where the `polygon` column is a `geopandas.GeoSeries` and each geometry element is a `shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon`.

I transformed the dataset into a geodataframe:

```
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
dataset = GeoDataFrame(dataset)
```

And used the `set_geometry` function to assign the geometry column:

```
dataset = dataset.set_geometry("polygon")
```

Everything seems to be working fine and I am able to plot heatmaps using this GeoDataFrame.

The issue I am having is that I am trying to create a dataset grouping the population per area, but I also have to group the polygons, which I have been failing to do so.

the final dataset should look like this, with all the `zip` polygons with the same `area#` should be collapsed into a single row with a `MultiPolygon` geometry and the total of the `population` values:

```
    +------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
    | population |   area#  |                        polygon                         |
    +------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
    | 150        | 55       | MULTYPOLYGON ((-55.66788 40.04416, -55.66790 40.044... |
    | .          | .        | .                                                      |
    | .          | .        | .                                                      |
    | .          | .        | .                                                      |
    | 236667     | 155      | MULTYPOLYGON ((-155.04682 78.53585, -155.04680 78.5..  |
    +------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

I really don't need to follow the steps I outlined before, these are the steps I found here on Stack Overflow. I am ok doing something else from scratch.

Comment: I just added some edits to (I hope) clarify your intent a bit more in the title and question body for others who come along with a similar question. Feel free to [edit] further if I misrepresented anything or you think it could be more clear :)

Comment: Your solution is perfect and I could apply it to the problem. I will think about rephrasing the title, it does need some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geopandas spatial equivalent of a pandas `.groupby().aggreagte()` operation is [dissolve](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/aggregation_with_dissolve.html). Take a look through the docs, they're really helpful.

One key argument to note is the `aggfunc` argument. From the docs:

> The `aggfunc =` argument defaults to ‘first’ which means that the first row of attributes values found in the dissolve routine will be assigned to the resultant dissolved geodataframe. However it also accepts other summary statistic options as allowed by [**`pandas.groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) including:
>
> - ‘first’
> - ‘last’
> - ‘min’
> - ‘max’
> - ‘sum’
> - ‘mean’
> - ‘median’
>   function
>   string function name
>   list of functions and/or function names, e.g. [np.sum, ‘mean’]
>   dict of axis labels -> functions, function names or list of such.

If you're looking to group on `area`, and sum the populations within each area, as well as unify the polygons, you can use `aggfunc={"population": "sum"}`, e.g.:

```py
aggregated = dataset.dissolve("area#", aggfunc={"population": "sum"})
```